# Reledpar heading and subheading counter problem

Tags: sectioning, reledmac, reledpar

Dear fellow tex enthusiasts,

I am very much enjoying the reledmac/reledpar packages and it has been tremendously helpful. One thing I find problematic still is that the subsection within the reledmac's page environment does not take over the numbering of the previous subsection, so that in effect we have

> Chapter 1
>   -beginning of pages environment-
>   Left page section 1.1
>   Left page subsection 1.1.1
>   Right page subsection 1.0.1
>   -end of pages environment-

How is it possible to have the numbering on the right page take over from where the left page had left off?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[
  draft,
  nopbinverse,
  widthliketwocolumns,
  series={A,B,C},]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\chapter{testchapter}

Introductory statements.

\begin{pages}   
    \begin{Leftside} 
                \beginnumbering 
        \pstart[\section{Abhidharmako\'sa 4.1--8}\\\subsection{Sanskrit}]\pend

    \pstart Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa in Sanskrit \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}  

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
\pstart[\subsection{Tibetan}]\pend

    \pstart Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa  in Tibetan \pend
\endnumbering
 %
\end{Rightside} 
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a feature of reledpar. Normally, your left subsection are // to your right subsection (because left side is generally a translation of right side).

There is no option (actually) to change this feature. Please open a github issue.

However, there is a quite simple workaround. Add

```
\makeatletter
\let\set@sectcountR\relax
\makeatother
```

To your preamble.

However, this feature is combined with two other ones:

- by default, the right section title are not add to the table of contents. You can change it using `\eledsectnotoc{}` in your preamble
- by default, the section mark (for the page header) are take only from one side. You can't tell to reledpar to use both side. Please open an issue for this problem.

by the way, your MWE does not work, as you didn't add any content to your pstart. You don't need to have an empty pstart to use optional argument to insert your section. You don't need, also, to add `\\` between headers.

So a (partially) good file would be

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[
  draft,
  noend, 
  nopbinverse,
  widthliketwocolumns,
  series={A,B,C},]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\makeatletter
\let\set@sectcountR\relax
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{testchapter}

Introductory statements.

\begin{pages}   
    \begin{Leftside} 
                \beginnumbering 
        \pstart[\section{Abhidharmako\'sa 4.1--8}\subsection{Sanskrit}]

    Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa in Sanskrit 
    \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}  

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
\pstart[\subsection{Tibetan}]

    Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa  in Tibetan \pend
\endnumbering

\end{Rightside} 
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

However, as your edit (if I understand well) a text in two language, I would respect the symetry of title (especially, because you could get problem of synchronisation in other case).

So

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[
  draft,
  nopbinverse,
  widthliketwocolumns,
  series={A,B,C},]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\chapter{testchapter}

Introductory statements.

\begin{pages}   
    \begin{Leftside} 
                \beginnumbering 
        \pstart[
          \section{Abhidharmako\'sa 4.1--8}
        \subsection{Sanskrit}]

    Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa in Sanskrit \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}  

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
\pstart[
  \section{Abhidharmako\'sa 4.1--8}
\subsection{Tibetan}
]

    Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa  in Tibetan \pend
\endnumbering
 %
\end{Rightside} 
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

But a more logical presentation would be

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[
  draft,
  nopbinverse,
  widthliketwocolumns,
  series={A,B,C},]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\chapter{testchapter}

Introductory statements.

\begin{pages}   
    \begin{Leftside} 
                \beginnumbering 
        \pstart[
        \section{Sanskrit} 
        \subsection{Abhidharmako\'sa 4.1--8}
        ]

    Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa in Sanskrit \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}  

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
\pstart[
  \section{Tibetan}
  \subsection{Abhidharmako\'sa 4.1--8}
]

    Here is a verse from the Abhidharmako\'sa  in Tibetan \pend
\endnumbering
 %
\end{Rightside} 
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Extremely useful and helpful comment! If the headings on the right page do not show up in the ToC, that changes everthing.